# Get transceiver informations through SNMP on Dell switch

Tags: dell, snmp, oid

From Dell PowerSwitch N4000 Series, I want to get information about transceiver through SNMP, like Wavelength, Receive Power

Example:

```
# show interfaces tengigabitethernet 1/0/5 transceiver detail

Type.............................. SFP+
Media............................. 10GBASE-LR
Serial Number..................... F0123456789
Dell EMC Qualified................ Yes
Data Rate......................... multirate
Wavelength........................ 1310
Receive Power..................... -3.131
```

Regardless firmware version (considere latest), I can't found valid OID. How monitor these informations ?

Best regards,

Comment: Did you try snmpwalk to find it? I know that librenms can collect it, so could check there for where it normally finds it.

Comment: Yes, but no result. Sometime, like Mikrotik, it's possible to call script by SNMP to get informations not available by default. If not possible to get information directly, I search a workaround. I can't believe that no people have ever encountered the problem on these equipments.

Comment: Ask Dell support?

Comment: You should download the appropriate MIB files and check them.

Answer (score 2):

I have Dell support answer.

These informations are available through "1.3.6.1.4.1.674.10895.500.2.6132.1.1.43.1.18.1.6" OID.

BUT, this OID is available since the firmware 6.7. Currently, I don't have switch with this version and wouldn't update for now.

I just share dell's answer.